# multiple ordering on categories in Mysql architecture

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a design issue with my **Mysql MyISAM** tables.

One of my tables contains a list of 'categories', (approx 100 rows)

```
id   |catcode      |name
-------------------------------
1     @01           lorem
2     @0101         ipsum
3     @02           dolor
```

Another table contains 'products'. (approx 28.000 rows)

```
id   |cats      |name      ...
---------------------------
1     @01@02     lorem     ...
2     @0101      ipsum     ...  
3     @02@0101   dolor     ...
```

in my products table, I define the list of categories where they belong to.

that's working perfectly, but now:

I'd like to customize the ordering they appear depending on the category selected.
At the moment, I have a column with the id of the categorie in my product table, but this seams very dirty (ordering_1, ordering_2, ordering_3, ...)
Especially because each product appears in only 2 or 3 different categories, so most of the columns are just empty:

```
 id   |cats      |name      |ordering_1    |ordering_2   |ordering_3  ...
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    1     @01@02     lorem      17                           12
    2     @0101      ipsum                     13            
    3     @02@0101   dolor                     21            8
```

I'd like to use a third table to determine the ordering, but how?

The basic idea is to have a table with the categories and an 'ordering' list, but one of these lists contains all the products! (the main category) I suppose it would be veeery slow to do a request with 28.000 id in it...

How to handle this?

Comment: What DB engine are you using? Please use only the appropriate tags.

Comment: @juergend ok I'm adding it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use foreign keys and a join table to link products with categories, instead of your `catcode` construct.

Create the table structure somewhat like the following (example is for MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE category (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE product_category (
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  category_id INT NOT NULL,
  ordering INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id, category_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then to get all products in a particular category sorted as defined for this category, query them like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product p LEFT JOIN product_category pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
    WHERE pc.category_id = 1
    ORDER BY pc.ordering ASC;
```

`1` is the category id in this. You could also query by category name for example:

```
SELECT * FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_category pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
    LEFT JOIN category c ON pc.category_id = c.id
    WHERE c.name = "foo"
    ORDER BY pc.ordering ASC;
```

Comment: Interesting, Thanks, I'm quite new to mysql... but the thing is, I use the categories this way so I can search by inheritance.. when looking up for 01, I know I also get the children's.. (0101, 0102,010201 ..) can this be combined with this technique?

Comment: You could still use your catcode within the category table, just don't use it to link products to categories.